# Passing implementation of typed interface as a parameter

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a typed interface which I want to pass as a parameter. But the compiler (or the runtime if I add an explicit cast) doesn't like that.

Interface/Class definitions:

```
interface IModel { ... }
class ActualModelA : IModel { ... }
class ActualModelB : IModel { ... }

interface IView<T> where T : IModel { ... }
class ActualViewA : IView<ActualModelA> { ... }
class ActualViewB : IView<ActualModelB> { ... }
```

Here is the method where it shall be passed to:

```
static void Test(IView<IModel> view) { ... }

static void Main()
{
    var view = new ActualViewA();
    
    Test(view); // fails at compile time 
    Test((IView<IModel>) view); // compiles, but fails at runtime
}
```

the compile error is `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ActualViewA' to 'IView<IModel>'` which doesnt fully makes sense to me since `ActualView` implements `IView<ActualModelA>` and `ActualModelA` implements `IModel`.

What am I missing here?
The `Test()` shall be able to receive an object of `ActualViewA` and `ActualViewB`.

Comment: In the same logic `IList<Cow>` would be the same as `IList<Animal>`, but what would happen if tried to do `list.Add(new Chicken);` on the list of cows that I view as a list of animals? I would advise to read up on contravariance and covariance. Depending on information not provided here there might be an easy fix (`interface IView<out T> ...`, but from the provided code it's impossible to tell if that would be allowed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `ActualViewA` does not extend `IView<IModel>`, but "only" `IView<ActualModelA>`. To remedy this you can make `Test` a generic method with variation on the `IModel`. Like this:

```cs
static void Test<T>(IView<T> view) where T : IModel { ... }
```